Find the value $Q$ from the given system of equations

We have some equations $$
\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{l}
        a^2+b^2=9 &\\
c^2+d^2=4 &\\
        ad-bc=6 &\\
\textrm{max}(ac)=k &\\
x^2+2xy-y^2=2k &\\
\textrm{min}((x^2+y^2)^2)=Q
    \end{array} 
\right.$$
Find the value $Q$ where $a,b,c,d,k,x, y\in\mathbb{R}$

We have
\begin{array}{l}
        a\cdot d+b\cdot(-c)\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot\sqrt{c^2+d^2} &\\
        \implies ad-bc\le6 
         \end{array}
But we are given that $ad-bc=6$ $\implies\frac{a}{b}=\frac{-c}{d}=\frac{1}{p}$ $\textrm{(say)}$
$\implies$
\begin{array}{l}
        a^2+a^2p^2=9 &\\
        c^2+c^2p^2=4 &\\
  \implies \frac{a^2}{c^2}=\frac{9}{4} &\\
\implies \frac{a}{c}=\pm\frac{3}{2}         \end{array}
Now we have $ad-bc=6$ and $ad+bc=0$
$\implies \boxed{ad=3}$ and $\boxed{bc=-3}$ 
$\implies \boxed{ac=\frac{-3}{p}}$
$\implies a^2c^2=\frac{9}{p^2}$ 
$\implies a^2c^2\cdot\frac{a^2}{c^2}=\frac{9}{p^2}\cdot\frac94$ 
$\implies p^2=\frac{81}{4a^4}$ 
$\implies a^2\left(1+\frac{81}{4a^4}\right)=9$ 
$\implies a^2+\frac{81}{4a^2}=9$ 
Now from AM-GM inequality, minimum of $a^2+\frac{81}{4a^2}$ is $9$
$\implies a^2=\frac{81}{4a^2}$ $$\implies \boxed{a=\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt2}}$$
Similarly, $$\implies \boxed{c=\pm\sqrt2}$$
$$\implies \boxed{\textrm{max}(ac)=3=k}$$
Now we have, $$x^2+2xy-y^2=6$$
Let $z=x+iy$
$\implies z^2=x^2+2ixy-y^2$ 
$\implies \Re(z^2)+\Im(z^2)=6$
I cannot proceed after this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT
I solved the question using trigonometric substitution, it feels that I was on the wrong path previously.
Although if someone can do that part (finding $Q$) via complex numbers, it'll be appreciated.

What does $\max(ac)=k$ mean?

@RobPratt maximum possible value of $ac$

So you are trying to simultaneously maximize $ac$ and minimize $(x^2+y^2)^2$?

@RobPratt yes..

COMMENT.-The identity $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$ yields $9\times4=(ac+bd)^2+36$ so we have $ac+bd=0$. On the other hand
$$x^2+2xy-y^2=2k\implies (x^2+y^2)^2=4k^2-4xy(x^2-y^2)$$ and the RHS can be written as two equal functions of $S=x^2-y^2$ and $P=xy$ as follows
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=2S^2-4kS+4k^2=8P^2-8kP+4k^2$$
Assuming as true your value $k=3$ one has
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=2S^2-12S+36=8P^2-24P+36$$ The minimum of $f(S)=2S^2-12S+36$ is equal to $18$ at $S=3$ and the minimum of $g(P)=8P^2-24P+36$ is equal to the same $18$ at $P=1.5$ this way we have for the minimums
$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=3\\xy=\dfrac32\end{cases}$$ solving this system one has
$$x^2=\dfrac{3\pm3\sqrt2}{2}\\y^2=\dfrac{\pm3\sqrt2-3}{2}$$ we get the same minimum value $18$
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=(\pm3\sqrt2)^2=18$$ which shows that we could stop calculating the minimum for the functions $f(S)$ or $g(P)$ above. (However I have to say that I don't understand completely this last fact).

I forgot that we can do trigonometric substitution in this case. It came to my mind just now.
Let 
$x=r\cos w$ and $y=r\sin w$
Now, $x^2+y^2=r^2$ 
And to find $Q$ we need to minimise $r^2$ as $Q=r^4$
We have 
$r^2\cos^2 w-r^2\sin^2 w+2r^2\cos^2 w\sin^2 w=6$ 
$\implies r^2(\cos(2w)+\sin(2w))=6$ 
$\implies r^2=\frac{6}{\cos(2w)+\sin(2w)}$ 
$\implies \textrm{min}(r^2)=\frac{6}{\sqrt2}$ $$\implies \boxed{Q=18}$$
